# Required parameter is missing error while writing to bigQuery with google.cloud.bigquery in Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics-api

I am loading a New Line Delimited JSON to bigQuery using the following code snippet in Python 2.7:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
dataset = bigquery_client.dataset('testGAData')
table_ref = dataset.table('gaData')
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref)

with open('gaData.json', 'rb') as source_file:
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
    job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(
        source_file, table, job_config=job_config)
```

It returns me the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 897, in load_table_from_file
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(exc.response)
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/test-project-for-experiments/jobs?uploadType=resumable: Required parameter is missing
```

Why am I getting this error? How can I fix this? Has anyone else faced a similar issue? Thanks in advance.
Edit: Added last para, included python imports and corrected the indents.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Also, where is the `bigquery_client` initialized? Also, take a look at the [docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_file.html). It seems that you're missing lots of non-optional variables.

Comment: Already done so @kingJulian

Comment: @kingJulian specified the project Id and the location, still giving the same error.

Comment: Have you tried adding a full file path?

Comment: You’re missing the table_ref from the load_table_from_file call; don’t pass the table object you created.

Comment: Adding to @elithrar's info, check [this](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html),  under *Table Operations->Upload table data from a file*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Issues observed with the initial code**

- You are missing the schema for your table. You can either use `job_config.autodetect = True` or `job_config.schema = [bigquery.SchemaField("FIELD NAME", "FIELD TYPE")]`.
- From the documentation, you should set `` job_config.source_format = `bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON` `` for a JSON file source
- You should pass your`table_ref` variable as an argument instead your `table` variable in `bigquery_client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table, job_config=job_config)`

[Link](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage.html#table-operations) to the documentation

**Working Code**

The below code works for me. I am using python 3 and google-cloud-bigquery v1.5

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
dataset_id, table_id = "TEST_DATASET", "TEST_TABLE"
data_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref = data_ref.table(table_id)
file_path = "path/to/test.json"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
#job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.schema = [bigquery.SchemaField("Name", "STRING"), bigquery.SchemaField("Age", "INTEGER")]

with open(file_path, 'rb') as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_ref, location='US', job_config=job_config)

job.result()

print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(job.output_rows, dataset_id, table_id))
```

Output

`>> Loaded 2 rows into TEST_DATASET:TEST_TABLE.`